# python Dataframe difference with filter in one line

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find difference between two columns in a Dataframe but want to apply filter.

Below is what I'm trying to do

```
((df['column1']-df['column2'])/(df['totalcolumn'])).idxmax()
```

above gives me result but I want to consider only rows in which Column1>0 and Column2>0.

can anyone help me?

Comment: filter your df before doing the calculation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.query('column1 > 0 and column2 > 0') \
  .eval('(column1 - column2) / totalcolumn').idxmax()
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply get the subset of your dataframe that you are interested in first:

```
sub_df = df.loc[(df.column1 > 0) & (df.column2 > 0)]

(sub_df.column1 - sub_df.column2  / sub_df.totalcolumn).idxmax()
```

If it's really important that it's in one line (as your title suggests) you could do your filtering in that same line, but this is inefficient and inelegant IMO:

```
(df.loc[(df.column1 > 0) & (df.column2 > 0), 'column1'] -
 df.loc[(df.column1 > 0) & (df.column2 > 0), 'column2'] /
 df.loc[(df.column1 > 0) & (df.column2 > 0), 'totalcolumn']).idxmax()
```

Comment: You can consolidate the condition a bit: `df.loc[df[['col1', 'col2']].gt(1).all(1)]`